# How do I remove text from EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have created a function which allows the user to enter text in EditText and then when the user clicks the send button it displays it on the screen in textView, but I want to remove the text from edittext once the user clicks on the send button and I only want it to display on the textview and nowhere else, how can I accomplish this?

```
private void addMessage() {
    final EditText myMessageField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageField);
    final TextView displayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.printMessage);
    Button btnSendMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

    btnSendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,22);
            displayText.setText(myMessageField.getText().toString());

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

in the `onClick` add this.

```
myMessageField.setText("");
```

it'll make the edittext text to blank

so it'll be like this:

```
   btnSendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,22);
            displayText.setText(myMessageField.getText().toString());
//erasing text from edittext
myMessageField.setText("");

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `editText.setText("");` ?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, a common use of this site is to mark an answer as correct and upvote it if you think it is useful. The answer is your choice. :) you are welcome

Comment: if the answer worked, accept it! btw check this link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence, android.widget.TextView.BufferType)

along with your string it requires a buffer type EDITABLE also